# MYSQL Table Error - 1064

Tags: mysql, create-table

Trying to create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE login (
        IdUser int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        username varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        pass varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (IdUser),
        ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$);
```

Doesn't seem to work properly. The error I'm getting in MYSQL is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$' at line 6

Comment: What's with the `$$` after `utf8`, is that intentional?

Comment: You're.. not.. storing `pass` in plain-text... Are you?

Comment: I am not. I'm hashing them #saltyyyyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bracket in the wrong spot:

```
PRIMARY KEY (IdUser),
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$);
                                                     ^----
```

should be

```
PRIMARY KEY (IdUser)   <--note removed comma
) ENGINE=MyIsam etc...
^---
```

You're treating those table options as they were fields, by placing them WITHIN the `()` field definition block.

Answer (score 0):

In my case some of the sql is working but mostly not working after changing Type=ENGINE.

```
CREATE TABLE `p4_acl_page` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `label` varchar(80) default NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyIsam;
```